# Reset a checkbox in Materialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I have a set of checkboxes that I want to uncheck if the user changes their dropdown selection, and I am using the Materialize checkbox.

I have a function that gets triggered fine when the value changes, and I've confirmed that. I also know you have to reinitialize certain form fields on Materialize if you use Javascript to update their values, but I can't seem to find how to do that for checkboxes in their documentation.

I tried using the good ol' .prop("checked", "true") trick, but that doesn't seem to reinitialize the checkbox with the updated property.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of code showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

materialize css version : 1.0.0

```
//Find checkbox if checkbox is checked:
 if($('#your_check_box_id').is(':checked'))
//Uncheck
  $('#your_check_box_id').prop("checked", false);
```